# How to do bitwise unsigned (zero-fill) right shift in Dart?

Tags: bit-manipulation, dart

How do I perform bitwise unsigned right shift / zero-fill right shift in Dart?

Something like this for instance:

```
foo >>> 2
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Zero-fill right shift requires a specific integer size. Since integers in Dart are of arbitrary precision the '>>>' operator doesn't make sense there.

The easiest way to emulate a zero-fill right shift is to bit-and the number first.

Example:

```
(foo & 0xFFFF) >> 2 // 16 bit zero-fill shift
(foo & 0xFFFFFFFF) >> 2 // 32 bit shift.
```

#### Update 2021:

Dart integers are now 64 bit. Since Dart 2.14 the `>>>` operator shifts the 64 bit integer and fills the most significant bits with 0.

Comment: seven years later, dart integers are 64 bit and they're working on it https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/120

Comment: This has now been added to Dart as a native feature, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68612095/6509751).

Answer (score 5):

The [triple-shift operator](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/120), i.e. bitwise unsigned right shift of integers has now been added as of Dart 2.14.

#### Triple-shift `>>>` operator in Dart

You can simply use this [starting with Dart version 2.14](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/478#issuecomment-889181121):

```dart
var foo = 42;
foo >>> 2;
```

In order to enable this for your app by default, you must upgrade your SDK constraint in `pubspec.yaml`:

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.14.0-0 <3.0.0'
```

---

[Learn more about the operator in the docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/int/%3E%3E%3E.html).

#### Pre Dart 2.14

If you have not yet upgraded to Dart 2.14, you can simply use this function:

```dart
/// Bitwise unsigned right shift of [x] by [s] bits.
///
/// This function works as `>>>` does starting with Dart 2.14.
int urs(int x, int s) => s <= 0 ? x : (x >> s) & (0x7fffffffffffffff >> (s - 1));
```

This works because integers are always 64-bit in Dart nowadays.

Comment: The "Pre Dart 2.14" (and post Dart 2.0) variant doesn't work. Doing `& 0xffffffffffffffff` is a no-op on a 64-bit integer.
You need something quite a lot more complicated, sadly. Something like `int urs(int x, int s) => s <= 0 ? x : (x >> s) & (0x7fffffffffffffff >> (s - 1));` perhaps.

Comment: @lrn I see - I updated it to use your suggestion for now. I will remove the section once Dart 2.14 lands on stable.

Answer (score 2):

You could define a utility function to use:

```
int zeroFillRightShift(int n, int amount) {
  return (n & 0xffffffff) >> amount;
}
```

That assumes you have 32-bit unsigned integers and that's ok if you do have.