# Does dart have operator >>>?

Tags: dart

The dart docs [list of operators](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#operators) includes `>>>`, it is also in the [Dart 2.2 Language Spec](https://dart.dev/guides/language/spec). However, it's not included in the list of overridable operators, [this answer from 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11748886/1013719) says that it doesn't (or didn't) exist, and [dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/) rejects `3 >>> 1`. Is this just a mistake in the docs, or does the operator do something I can't figure out?

Comment: Issue still open: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/120

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: not yet (as of July 2019)

Here's the master tracking issue: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/30886