# Using the triple-shift (>>>) operator in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, bit-shift

Supposedly Dart 2.14 included the triple shift operator (`>>>`), but when I try to use it I get an error:

```dart
print(0xff >>> 1);
```

The compiler highlights the last `>` of the three and says:

> Expected an identifier.

This is true on my local machine and in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true). Both are using the version of Dart 2.14 shipped with Flutter 2.5.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a problem with the release?

Comment: Referring to docs https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.1/dart-core/int/operator_triple_shift.html it says not implemented yet.

Comment: Did you set 2.14 as the minimum Dart SDK version in `pubspec.yaml`?

Comment: @jamesdlin, you're right. I forgot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can refer to my [related answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68612095/6509751).

---

Any **language features** that are introduced in a given version require that version as the **minimum constraint** for your project. This means you need to update your `pubspec.yaml`:

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.14.0 <3.0.0'
```

Now, you can use:

```dart
var foo = 42;
foo >>> 2;
```

Comment: Oops, I should have known that. Thank you. Any idea why it doesn't work in DartPad?

Comment: @Suragch The null-safety toggle suggests that DartPad is capable of running at different compatibility levels.  Even though it's "Based on ... Dart SDK 2.14.0" probably doesn't mean that it's using 2.14.0 as the minimum SDK version.  It's probably a bug that should be reported.

Comment: Update: `>>>` works in DartPad now.

Answer (score 0):

If you compile this code, required Dart SDK version **2.14.1**.

> Dart language site’s documentation and examples use version 2.13.4 of the Dart SDK.
> https://dart.dev/tools/sdk.

So when you are trying with Flutter, It uses SDK version less than **2.14.1**.

> Download the latest Flutter SDK
> https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows and replace
> the old one. Update your **pubspec.yaml** file

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.14.0 <3.0.0"
```

To run your code without Flutter app:

> Download latest Dart SDK from https://dart.dev/tools/sdk/archive

- Create a project with Android Studio IDE.
- Create a new Flutter project.
  Select **Dart** from the left menu.
- Locate **Dart SDK path**, that you downloaded(Must be extracted)
- Provide your **project name** and **location**.
- Create a Dart file and write these lines of code.

  ```
    void main() {
      final value = 0x22;
      print("Current value : $value");
      print("Unsigned shift right value is : ${(value >>> 4)}");
    }
  ```

  Output is

  ```
    F:/Dart/dart-sdk/bin/dart.exe --enable-asserts F:\Flutter\TestDartLanguage\main.dart
    Current value : 34
    Unsigned shift right value is : 2

    Process finished with exit code 0
  ```

Enjoy happy coding. Thanks

Comment: Since DartPad uses 2.14.0, that's why it doesn't work there?

Comment: @Suragch: Although Dart 2.14 added the unsigned shift operator (>>>) and DartPad also uses 2.14 But why this code not working in DartPad is quite unknown.  Click to details: https://dart.dev/guides/language/evolution#dart-214